# Inline Musical repeat (left and right) sign

Tags: math-mode, inline, music

I have an old document, for what I don't have the original LaTex-code. So I need to rewrite it. I stumbled upon some fancy examples using musical symbols. For the notes i found some packages (like "wasysym" or "harmony") wich allow inline usage. But for the [musical repeat sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeat_sign) i can't find anything to use it inline.

Here the example:

[image: To be Texed code]

This is the code-environment I'm working with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[USenglish,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    $S \to A ~ | ~ AS ~ | ~ D$ & $C \to ~ | ~$      \\
    $A \to BB ~ | ~ CBC$       & $D \to S ~ | ~ SS$ \\
    $B \to CC ~ | $
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

An help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The `leadsheets` package – more precisely its `musicsymbols` library provides `\leftrepeat`, `\rightrepeat` and `\leftrightrepeat`

Comment: Surprisingly it's not even in lilyglyph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your own: `\repeat` and `\frepeat`.  EDITED to also use `wasysym` symbols for the notes and increased `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[USenglish,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stackengine,wasysym}
\def\repeat{%
  \stackanchor{.}{.}%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.3pt}{\normalbaselineskip}%
  \kern0.5pt%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\normalbaselineskip}%
  \kern1pt%
}
\def\frepeat{%
  \kern1pt%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\normalbaselineskip}%
  \kern0.5pt%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.3pt}{\normalbaselineskip}%
  \stackanchor{.}{.}%
}
\newcommand\vsep{\quad | \quad}
\begin{document}
\tabcolsep=40pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    $S \to A \vsep AS \vsep \frepeat D$ & 
      $C \to \quarternote \vsep \twonotes$\\
    $A \to BB \vsep CBC$       & 
      $D \to S \repeat \vsep S \repeat S$ \\
    $B \to CC \vsep \halfnote$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]